# further filter GROUP_CONCAT value in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I use GROUP_CONCAT to concatenate `cate_id`s that share the same `pub_id`:

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id)
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id;
```

The result is as expected:

```
mysql> SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID)
    -> FROM book_mast
    -> GROUP BY pub_id;
+--------+-----------------------+
| pub_id | GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID) |
+--------+-----------------------+
| P001   | CA002,CA004           | 
| P002   | CA003,CA003           | 
| P003   | CA001,CA003           | 
| P004   | CA005,CA002           | 
| P005   | CA001,CA004           | 
| P006   | CA005,CA001           | 
+--------+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

But, how can I further filter out the result in the same SQL query, e.g. I only want to output rows whose value is `CA005,CA002`?

Answer (score 2):

YIu could add the filter in where

```
SELECT pub_id,GROUP_CONCAT(CATE_ID)
FROM book_mast
WHERE CATE_ID IN  ('CA005','CA001')
GROUP BY pub_id
having count(distinct CATE_ID)  = 2
```

in this way you can filter also anorder values

Comment: No, I mean I only want rows with GROUP_CONCAT value `CA005,CA002`, not `IN` one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
SELECT pub_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cate_id ORDER BY cate_id) as cate_ids
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id
HAVING cate_ids = 'CA002,CA005';
```

Note the `ORDER BY` because the ordering of the values is indeterminate without it.

That said, `GROUP_CONCAT()` is rather inefficient.  A more efficient method to get `pub_id`s in exactly those two categories is:

```
SELECT pub_id
FROM book_mast
GROUP BY pub_id
HAVING SUM(cate_id = 'CA002') = 1 AND   -- has CA002
       SUM(cate_id = 'CA005') = 1 AND   -- has CA005
       COUNT(*) = 2                     -- only has these two
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try